Links not working when serving Angular site from Apache2
I'm attempting to build a PWA for a capstone project course (ie. I'm somewhat of a noob). When I run ng serve in my development environment, my app runs perfectly. However, whenever I run npm i -g http-server from the dist folder, or even when I copy the contents of the dist folder to my apache2 server, the landing page works, but my links in my navbar do not work.
What am I not understanding?
I changed all links from href to routerLink.
No luck.
My website is www.interlinksfis.com
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="landing">InterlinkSFIS</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" routerLink="academicadvising">Academic Advising</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="events">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="yourcommunity">Your Community</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="transportation">Transportation</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="healthcare">HealthCare</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a routerLink="contact" class="nav-link" >Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" routerLink="login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>```



Did you notice that your app has errors? ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')     at GD (main-3OPBH4FW.js:7:68658)

No.  How did you figure out those errors?

Press F12 to open dev tools. you will see the console.

Thanks, that helped a lot.  Been a while since I had even thought to open the console.  I'm currently troubleshooting and reading some article about "hydration."  I'll report back if I make any progress.

I tried adding ngSkipHydration to the <app-root>  tag.   When I ran ng-serve  the errors disappear.  However, when I deploy the app to the server, I still get the ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')   

It's hard to tell what went wrong from your statement. My suggestion is that you can start with a development build locally.

So I got it working. My guess is that I was not building the app correctly. I ran ng build --configuration production --base-href "https://my.website.com"
